# How to loop over multiple lines using getResourceAsStream()?

Tags: java, scala, stream, resources, classloader

I have the following Scala code:

```
  @Test def test2() = {
    try {
      val data_in = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("com/myProject/myPackage/myInput.txt"))

      val data_out = MyTool.process(data_in)

      println(data_out)

    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>

        println("process failed")
    }
  }
```

---

The code works fine when myInput.txt has only one line. However, I am wondering when myInput.txt has multiple lines, how do I break `data_in` to multiple lines and process each line using `MyTool.process()` ?

Thanks!

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-split-string-example

Split your string on `\n`?

Comment: Java provides the Scanner class which is iterable or you can use BufferedReader.   There might be other Scala tools for this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **scala.io.Source.fromInputStream** like this

```
  import scala.io.Source

  @Test def test2() = {
    try {
      val data_in = getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("com/myProject/myPackage/myInput.txt")

      for (line <- Source.fromInputStream(data_in).getLines()) {
          val data_out = MyTool.process(line)

          println(data_out)
      }

    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>

        println("process failed")
    }
  }
```